# Hide scrollbar in Firefox for windows?

Tags: windows, firefox

I'm looking for a fix or extension like this one for [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lkfmjedfjkmfmckgcadelnfjebccjdcf) for firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=stylish) and then this [stylish userscript](http://userstyles.org/styles/5449/scrollbar-hidden-hide-scrollbars-totally)